# joining columns rstudio

Tags: sql, rstudio

I have a following code, which works, but i'd like S.imie and S.nazwisko to function as a single column called 'osoba'. How can I do that? when i try to S.imie + S.nazwisko AS osoba, it shows me 0s.

```
dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT S.imie, S.nazwisko, D.kierunek, D.stacjonarne 
           FROM student S LEFT JOIN dane D ON S.Id = D.id_osoba
           WHERE D.kierunek LIKE '%ekonomia%' AND D.stacjonarne LIKE 'nie'")
```

thats what i would like to get:

```
 osoba               kierunek   stacjonarne

1       Aleksy Wojciechowski eKONOMIA         nie
2     Amadeusz   Leszczyński eKONOMIA         nie
3       August    Przybylski ekonomia         nie
4       Feliks     Sosnowski ekonomia         nie
5         Igor      Bielecki eKONOMIA         nie
6        Jacek    Bednarczyk ekonomia         nie
7      Jaromir         Skiba eKONOMIA         nie
```

Comment: try  CONCAT(S.imie, ' ', S.nazwisko) as osoba,

Comment: Error in result_create(conn@ptr, statement) : no such function: CONCAT

Comment: What SQL?  SQLServer? postgresql? sqlLite?   For SQLite  S.imie || S.nazwisko as osoba,